# jquery .append() not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append some text to the dynamically created div. I am doing this inside the .each() function. The problem the text is not getting appended. Can someone please help me with this. Here it is what I am trying to do

```
         $('<div class="window" id="window'+i+'" />')
                .append($('<p id="country'+i+'">').text($(this).find('COUNTRY').text()))
                .appendTo('body');
                var j = 0;
                $(this).find('TO').each(function(){
                    var $name = $(this).text();
                    alert("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@::::"+$name);
                    j +=1;
                    $('<#id="window'+i+'" />').append($('<p id="to'+j+'">Test</p>'));
                });
```

Please help me by letting me know where I am going wrong with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is this element ?

```
$('<#id="window'+i+'" />')
```

Would you mean:

```
$('#window'+i)
```

?

Comment: are you trying to create an element or select it?

Comment: @fliim: uhh! yes, i meant the same thing. It was a very silly mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is wrong. it should be

```
$('div[id="window'+i+'"]').append($('<p id="to'+j+'">Test</p>'));
```

or since you have an id just use the ID selector

```
$('#window' + i)
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: he's not selecting the `div`, he's creating it

Comment: @jackwanders  actually my code has nothing to do with his creation part.. its his selecting inside the each loop

Comment: Yeah, I saw that after I commented.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your problem is with this bit:

```
$(this).find('COUNTRY').text()
```

I'm guessing 'COUNTRY' is the `id` of the element you're looking for? If so, try:

```
$(this).find('#COUNTRY').text()
```

Likewise, this selector:

```
$(this).find('TO')
```

may need to be changed to

```
$(this).find('#TO')
```

It depends on if `'COUNTRY'` and `'TO'` are IDs, classes, etc. Lastly, as everyone else has pointed out:

```
$('<#id="window'+i+'" />')
```

is an invalid selector. If you are trying to create an element, you want:

```
$('<div id="window'+i+'" />')
```

if you are trying to select an existing element, try:

```
$('#window'+i)
```

Comment: also `$(this).find('TO').each`

Comment: @jackwanders: No the i am not searching for the id COUNTRY, it is a xml element I am looking for. Basically I am parsing the xml doc and displaying the contents in HTML. All I went wrong was with the selectors.